# How to run multiple inter-dependent maven modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi

I have a multi-module maven OSGi project. I am using the maven-assembly-plugin to organise the different jars into a central folder, from which the OSGi container will be loading the various project modules:

**dist pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dist</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>distro-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <parent>
        <groupId>rev</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

The module jars get put into the central folder as I wish to. I, however, with time, can't really keep track of how the module dependencies relate to each other. For example, a certain module might need that another module be started before it can get executed properly. How can I guarantee that before a **module-B** gets started, a **module-A** will first be started - I would like to configure this in a way that some code handles the order of execution?

This is the error I get when such order of execution is not right. I don't think the bundles get installed.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer [2](R 2.0): missing requirement [OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer [2](R 2.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.bw.osgi.provider.able)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[OSGiDmHelloWorldConsumer [2](R 2.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.bw.osgi.provider.able)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:984)
    at main.App.initialize(App.java:46)
    at main.App.main(App.java:22)
```

Below is the class `public class App {}` that throws the error:

**App**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BundleException, URISyntaxException {
        App app = new App();
        app.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() throws BundleException, URISyntaxException {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // make sure the cache is cleaned
        map.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);

        map.put("ds.showtrace", "true");
        map.put("ds.showerrors", "true");

        FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
        Framework framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(map);

        System.out.println("Starting OSGi Framework");
        framework.init();
        loadScrBundle(framework);

        String baseDir = "/D:/Maven-Assembly-Plugin-MM/dist/target/dist-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/plugins/";

        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:" + baseDir + "core-1.0.jar");
        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:" + baseDir + "clientfile-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:" + baseDir + "dist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");

        List<Bundle> bundles = new ArrayList<Bundle>();

        for (Bundle bundle : framework.getBundleContext().getBundles()) {
            bundle.start();
            bundles.add(bundle);

            System.out.println("Bundle Name: " + bundle.getSymbolicName());
            System.out.println("Bundle ID: " + bundle.getBundleId());
            if (bundle.getRegisteredServices() != null) {
                for (ServiceReference<?> serviceReference : bundle.getRegisteredServices())
                    System.out.println("\tRegistered service: " + serviceReference);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total Bundles: " + bundles.size());
    }

    private void loadScrBundle(Framework framework) throws URISyntaxException, BundleException {
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org/apache/felix/scr/ScrService.class");
        if (url == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find the class org.apache.felix.scr.ScrService");
        String jarPath = url.toURI().getSchemeSpecificPart().replaceAll("!.*", "");
        System.out.println("Found declarative services implementation: " + jarPath);
        framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(jarPath).start();
    }
}
```

How can I go about resolving this? Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

The module jars get put into the central folder as I wish to. I, however, get the following error for all the modules except the felix modules when I try to run the project after calling mvn clean install, ie, all modules from the central maven repository, such as **org.apache.felix.framework** and **org.apache.felix.scr** are run in the OSGi container, except those I write myself.

**The Problem In Greater Detail**

I have published a the a very short version of the problem project in greater detail [**HERE**, Maven-Assembly-Plugin-MM](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/buhi9t0ftuqhqmw/AADCO18OPGcqUjNv2XlF5gsha?dl=0). [**This**, OSGi - Simple Hello World with services](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/07/osgi-hello-world-services.html), is the tutorial that I followed.

**Eclipse:**
Import > Existing Maven Projects > C:\***Path***\Maven-Assembly-Plugin-MM

Comment: Are you using plain vanilla Felix or Karaf? If you are on Karaf, have a look at the [feature deployer](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/provisioning.html). And the [karaf-maven-plugin](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/karaf-maven-plugin.html) to create the feature file based on your POM dependencies.

Comment: My dependencies are `org.apache.felix.framework` and `org.apache.felix.scr` and `org.osgi.core` @Ralf

Comment: Please provide the POM of the first failing bundle. Did you use the bundle plugin and packaging=bundle?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following Dropbox links here. Please post the relevant part (how you generate the OSGi metadata) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle loading order should not matter in OSGi applications.

But OSGi services might have dependencies to other services.

You can use a framework such as Declarative Services to easily manage dependencies (eg. using the [SCR annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html)).

You'll need the following plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>scr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        <!-- only needed at compile time, not at runtime -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Puce. Could you please point me to a sscce. I've been at this for days. I will really appreciate some help.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev I don't have a SSCCE, but here is some code I wrote for Drombler FX you can use as a sample, if you like. It has 3 dependencies (references) to other services: https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/blob/release-0.7/drombler-fx-core-standard-desktop-classic/src/main/java/org/drombler/fx/core/standard/desktop/classic/impl/ContentHandler.java

Comment: I only get errors for all the modules except the felix modules when I try to run the project after calling mvn clean install, ie, all modules from the central maven repository, such as org.apache.felix.framework and org.apache.felix.scr are run in the OSGi container, except those I write myself. I did an update on the question regarding this. @Puce

Comment: Hi @Puce. Thank you for the help in my question on OSGi. I'm still trying to grasp it, but I'm still a bit stuck. Could you please look at my question [**HERE:** Apache Maven Assembly Plugin not working with OSGi bundles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886012/apache-maven-assembly-plugin-not-working-with-osgi-bundles) and see if you could help. I will certainly appreciate any assistance you may be able to offer. It is a related to this one. Thank you in advance.